# I want to make a FloatView, but I don't know how to make it only show in the app

Tags: android

**I make a FloatView like this site,https://github.com/JackZhous/FloatView**

**target :**
This FloatView will disappear when the user presses the main screen, but the app switch screen will not disappear.

**problem :**
I modify the file...
FloatUtil.java line 81 mParams.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE;
->FloatUtil.java line 81 mParams.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_PANEL;

get error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.jack.zhou.floatview, PID: 15188
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jack.zhou.floatview/com.jack.zhou.floatview.MainActivity}: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2327)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:153)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1305)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:569)
    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:282)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
    at com.jack.zhou.floatview.floatutil.FloatUtil.createFloatView(FloatUtil.java:90)
    at com.jack.zhou.floatview.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2280)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:153) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1305) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

How can i solve it?

Answer (score 0):

this happen we permission not granted  ,WindowManager in android 23 and higher need special permission .

you should add this to mainfest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```

and use this to make user give you this permission

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
    if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(Activity.this)) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
        startActivityForResult(intent, i);
    }
}
```

not that i is integer you will used onActivityResult()